# How to disable backBarButtonItem displayed in current view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

After a view has been pushed onto the UINavigationController stack and is displayed I need to disable the Back button under certain circumstances, e.g., when data is being edited on that screen.

The following hides the Back button

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=YES;
```

but I need to disable it.

There are several other answers about how to hide it or suggest not displaying it in the first place, but these are not what I need to implement.

Comment: For the time being I solved this by creating a custom leftBarButtonItem view and have the action pop the view controller in the current view. Unfortunately there is no easy (and legit) way to get a standard left arrow button.

Comment: I added a feature request on apple.com to add a new enum for the standard left/right arrow buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement one of the delegate methods for your navigationController's navigation bar delegate. Take a look at the `[UINavigationBarDelegate navigationBar:shouldPopItem:]` method.

Returning YES or NO from this method will enable or disable the back button.

Comment: Doesn't this method control whether items are added (pushed) or removed (poped) from the navigation bar rather than the enabled state?

Comment: It's not as simple as this since this delegate selector is only responsible for the nav bar, not the controller.  If you implement this delegate selector and return YES then you'll see that the toolbar pops, but the controller doesn't.  I haven't tried to pop the controller, but I've read stories of other folks trying to do this and not getting being able to get the timing correct on the animation.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement one leftBarButtonItem (invisible and without effect)
add it into your current view (self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem)
and remove it to access your backButton.

Answer (score 0):

If you're fine that the whole navigation bar is disabled, an easy solution is

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Of course this doesn't work if you have other bar buttons that you want to keep enabled.